# What object did I see in the sky?

Tags: satellite, artificial-satellite, meteorite

Tonight, while looking at the night sky, I saw a moving object which I cannot assign to any cosmic or man-made object known to me.
The object looked like a star, and hadn't it been moving, it would have been indistinguishable from one. However, unlike usual objects in the night sky, its movement velocity was inconsistent, and its direction didn't follow a straight line, but kept digressing and then returning to the original path. It reminded me of a biker going through a crowd, or a car avoiding potholes. It moved quite quickly though, and traversed the sky in a couple of minutes.
What object is the description consistent with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does not sound astronomical. But in order to test for astronomical phenomenon you need to state date time (time zone) and location, and direction (roughly). Of course if it was cloudy. The free software Stellarium (stars planets, satellites + ...), in conjunction with Heavens Above (up to date satellite info) can answer most of these types of questions.